# How to get a microsoft.ink (XP Tablet PC SDK) app that works on windows 7 to work in winXP (not tablet edition)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, tablet-pc, microsoft.ink

I've written and tested an app that runs perfectly on Win7 using the [XP Tablet PC SDK 1.7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=b46d4b83-a821-40bc-aa85-c9ee3d6e9699&displaylang=en), but am having problems getting this to work on standard XP which a number of our clients use. I guess XP is missing some components that XP tablet edition would have - does anyone know where I can get these components - possibly a runtime distribution of XP Tablet PC SDK or something like that?

The occurs when trying to open the form with the ink related components on, the error is:

[image]

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{43FB1553-AD74-4EE8-88E4-3E6DAAC915DB} failed due to the following error:
80040154.
Error Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Ink.InkCollector..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Ink.InkCollector..ctor(IntPtr handle)
   at autoVHC.Uc_SquashedFrog.Init()
   at autoVHC.frmCheckList..ctor(VHCTOManager VHCTO, TemplateTree t) Error
Message: Microsoft.Ink Error to string:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM
class factory for component with CLSID
{43FB1553-AD74-4EE8-88E4-3E6DAAC915DB} failed due to the following error:
80040154.
   at Microsoft.Ink.InkCollector..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Ink.InkCollector..ctor(IntPtr handle)
   at autoVHC.Uc_SquashedFrog.Init()
   at autoVHC.frmCheckList..ctor(VHCTOManager VHCTO, TemplateTree t)
```

Microsoft.Ink has proven to be a headache, none of the tools in visual studio work for it (which is ok by me as I only used the ink collector) - and even that seems to have some weird quirks to it :( - like random null ref exceptions that don't really cause a problem. go figure.

Note: we must use this SDK as our clients use .Net2 and won't upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which may help - basically you need to include the `Mstpcrt.msm` merge module from `<PROGRAM FILES>\Microsoft Tablet PC Platform SDK\msm` and include it in your set-up project.